# Why is the distribution of d̄ normal? (d̄ = x̄₁ - x̄₂ when both sampling distributions are normal)

Tags: distributions, inference, two-sample

I'm learning about doing inference with two samples. $d̄ = x̄₁ - x̄₂$. [Sampling is independent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249363/why-is-the-distribution-of-d%CC%84-normal-d%CC%84-x%CC%84%E2%82%81-x%CC%84%E2%82%82-when-both-sampling-distrib?noredirect=1#comment474443_249363). Let's suppose $x̄₁$ and $x̄₂$ are both normally distributed. My understanding is that this means $d̄$ will also be normally distributed. Why is this?

I'm looking for an intuitive explanation, not a derivation of the pdf.

---

My attempt:

Say that these are our two sampling distributions:

[image]

How can we get $d̄ = 0$? Some possibilities:

- $x̄₁ = 10$ and $x̄₂ = 10$. P(this happening) = very unlikely * very very unlikely = not gonna happen.
- $x̄₁ = 20$ and $x̄₂ = 20$. P(this happening) = likely * very unlikely = very very unlikely.
- $x̄₁ = 30$ and $x̄₂ = 30$. P(this happening) = very unlikely * likely = very very unlikely.
- $x̄₁ = 40$ and $x̄₂ = 40$. P(this happening) = very very unlikely * very unlikely = not gonna happen.

So overall, $P(d̄ = 0)$ is the sum of all of these, which is a very small number.

What about $d̄ = 10$? How can we get that? Some possibilities:

- $x̄₁ = 15$ and $x̄₂ = 25$. P(this happening) = unlikely * unlikely = very unlikely.
- $x̄₁ = 17.5$ and $x̄₂ = 27.5$. P(this happening) = solid chance * solid chance = plausible.
- $x̄₁ = 20$ and $x̄₂ = 30$. P(this happening) = likely * likely = solid chance.

Hopefully you see where this is going. To construct the distribution of $d̄$'s, ask yourself, "How many ways can I get this value of $d̄$?" and "How likely is it that each of these ways occur?". Use those questions to arrive at the value for $P(d̄)$, and repeat this procedure for each $d̄$.

To help visualize, you could slide the bottom distribution. In the picture, 20 lines up with 20, 30 lines up with 30 etc. If you go "straight down" and subtract, you get zero. By "going straight down at all the different points", it allows you to calculate $P(d̄ = 0)$. To get $P(d̄ = x)$, offset the axis by $x$.

Comment: We have a huge number of relevant posts, giving you a wide array of answers to choose from.  For just a few of them, please search our site for [sum normal](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sum+normal).

Comment: I had been searching for "d-bar" and "two sample". Now that you've given me insight into what better search terms are, I've been looking, but have yet to find something that gives an intuitive explanation for why the distribution of d̄ looks the way it does. Of course, that doesn't mean it doesn't exist and it sounds like you're saying it does. So then, should I close this question, based on the assumption that it does exist and I haven't found it?

Comment: It's hard to find a direct intuitive explanation--I searched through several pages without finding one.  The only *intuitive* explanation I can recall seeing on this site is indirect, related to the [Central Limit Theorem.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=central%20limit%20theorem)  That says the sum of lots of independent identically distributed variables (which aren't too spread out) will be very close to Normally distributed.  Consequently, the sum of two Normal distributions will look like the sum of twice as many iid variables--and therefore will also be Normal.

Comment: In that case, it seems like the question requesting an intuitive explanation isn't a repeat - should I keep it (and clarify that I'm looking for an intuitive explanation rather than something like calculating the pdf)?

Comment: You should specify that you intend that all the variates involved in your difference of averages are independent (presuming that's the intent); marginal normality is not itself sufficient.